# Enable favicon on Apache 2.4 with SSL

Tags: django, apache

I have Django app and can serve favicon via it. But it is not recommended so I did it using Apache.

Previously I had HTTP 80 configs. After moving from HTTP to SSL 443 I cannot access the favicon on the server anymore.

The part of responsible config looks like:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>

        DocumentRoot /home/ubuntu/project/project/

        Alias /favicon.ico /home/ubuntu/project/static/favicon.ico
        Alias /static/ /home/ubuntu/project/static/

        <Location />
           Require host mysite.com
        </Location>

        <Directory /home/ubuntu/project/static>
            Require all granted
        </Directory>
    </VirtualHost>
```

Folder exists and favicon is located in it.

When I am trying to access favicon.ico I get 403:

```
Forbidden
You don't have permission to access /favicon.ico on this server.
```

How can I solve it?

**Updates:**

1. I have found [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/377186/apache-namevirtualhost-on-port-443-ignores-serveralias) that ServerAliases are ignored with SSL, so probably Aliases are ignored as well.
2. [Here](http://staticfiles.productiondjango.com/blog/failproof-favicons/) is good overview How to serve favicons with Django, but I want to do it only with Apache to minimize the number of requests to Django.
3. [Here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/873851/enable-favicon-on-apache-2-with-ssl) some developers suggested me to check favicon permissions but it didn't help.
4. The problem is in the root **location** directive which restricts access to the whole website. If somebody knows how to make exception just for favicon please post it in answer!

Comment: Any reason why you have to Alias the favicon and not just drop it on root ?

Comment: @Eric Yes, the reason is that documentRoot is different from location of favicon

Comment: Shouldn't it be Alias /favicon.ico "/home/ubuntu/project/static/favicon.ico" (with quotes)

Comment: @Eric I think it won't influence. With HTTP it was working fine. Also I am using Django and here is also simple config without quotes https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/howto/deployment/wsgi/modwsgi/

Comment: Why not putting a copy of your favicon.ico (not the alias) directly in your root folder?

Answer (score 0):

My solution was to remove:

```
    <Location />
       Require host mysite.com
    </Location>
```

and instead use:

```
    <Directory  /home/ubuntu/project/project>
       Require host mysite.com
    </Directory>
```

It helped to serve the favicon, but I still don't like it because I have removed the check of host on root url. Any other solutions are welcome!

Answer (score 0):

The path specified in the  parameter is not part of the URL, but part of the filesystem where your app is served.